# Method to determine maximum number of characters which fit into HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, typography

I have an HTML field and I want to determine the maximum number of characters that can be safely entered into that field without overflow with a given font and font size.

If the element is using courier new or some other fixed-width font and has no line breaks, this would be a trivial problem: simply enter text until it overflows the element, and count how many characters were used.

Using a font with different spacing per character, this becomes more difficult. Is there a way to safely calculate this, possibly configuring an arbitrary maximum or average word-length to ignore outliers such as "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" which would break the line more prematurely than normal.

The assumptions would likely be the width of the "widest" common character in the font and a maximum word length to account for the space lost on line breaks. Otherwise, I will provide a rough estimate with a safe amount of buffer ☺

To clarify, this is not about programatically preventing input over a certain length - these limits will be explicitly communicated beforehand. This is about determining *what* that limit is rather than fuzzily-estimating it.

Comment: add the text char by char to a div with a minimum width and see if the div gets wider. Do this off screen.estimate the width of the textbox.

Comment: @SiddharthSrinivasan, this is about obtaining that estimate in the first place, not preventing input over a certain length.

Comment: @CasparKleijne the div will not change dimensions based on the text inside.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Div in Memory
- Append the text char by char
- get the computed value of the width of the text according to the font and text size.

So you edit the code and wrap it in a loop:

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
newDiv.className ="fontVerdana"
newDiv.style ="display:inline-block;"


newDiv.innerText ="this is a test ";
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

// returns the width based on the content / 40px Verdana
alert("based on the content / 40px Verdana => "+ window.getComputedStyle(newDiv,null).getPropertyValue("width"));

newDiv.innerText ="this is a test that will show how big this box is";
// returns the width based on the content / 40px Verdana
alert("40px Verdana =>" + window.getComputedStyle(newDiv,null).getPropertyValue("width"));

newDiv.className ="fontSerif"
newDiv.innerText ="this is a test that will show how big this box is";
// returns the width based on the content / 20px Serif
alert("20px Serif => " + window.getComputedStyle(newDiv,null).getPropertyValue("width"));

newDiv.className ="fontMonoSpace"
newDiv.innerText ="this is a test that will show how big this box is";
// returns the width based on the content / 10px Monospace
alert("10px Monospace => " + window.getComputedStyle(newDiv,null).getPropertyValue("width"));
```

```css
.fontVerdana
{
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:40px;
}

.fontSerif
{
  font-family:serif;
  font-size:20px
}

.fontMonoSpace
{
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:10px;
}
```